# Replace multiple text in a text file using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, replace, text-files

I am trying to replace 3 text from a text file.I tried this-

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("W:\Test.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "Aron_", "Lori_")
strNewText1 = Replace(strText, "Aron", "Jason")   'Not working
strNewText2 = Replace(strText, "Sketa", "Skicia") 'Not working


Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("W:\Test.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText 
objFile.WriteLine strNewText1 'Not working
objFile.WriteLine strNewText2 'Not working


objFile.Close
```

i am not able to figure out how to do multiple replacement.The code working perfect for single replace function but not more than one...plz help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to call `Replace` on the results of the previous `Replace`:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("W:\Test.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "Aron_", "Lori_")
strNewText1 = Replace(strNewText, "Aron", "Jason")
strNewText2 = Replace(strNewText1, "Sketa", "Skicia")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("W:\Test.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText2 

objFile.Close
```

---

You could actually reuse a single variable, instead of having `strNewText`, `strNewText1`, `strNewText2`.

```
strText = Replace(strText, "Aron_", "Lori_")
strText = Replace(strText, "Aron", "Jason")
strText = Replace(strText, "Sketa", "Skicia")
```

and later:

```
objFile.WriteLine strText
```

---

Also, you might want to consider using regular expressions for matching multiple values at a time. (Search on SO for **VBScript regular expressions** or **VBA regular expressions**.)

Comment: i tried - strNewText = Replace(strText, "Aron_", "Lori_")
strNewText1 = Replace(strNewText, "Aron", "Jason") . but its not working..

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting an error, or is the file not being written, or is the text of the file not being changed?

Comment: only for the first Replace the file is being written and text is getting changed,but  for the second replace the text is not getting changed..

Comment: Just saw your edited section, it is working fine now by using single variable...Thanks for your awsome responese and timely help!!