# VBScript/ASP Classic - Parse and Replace Multiple Items from String

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

We have a department in the organization that was given a limited-length description field in a legacy application. They came up with their own acronyms and abbreviations for various phrases, which we would like to convert back to English phrases.

I'd like to have a better way to parse these descriptions than what I'm currently doing.

Sample Items:

```
Part #:         Description
-------------------------------------
10001           17OH 2P 2G TRK 2YR
10002           22OH 2P 3G TRK 1YR
```

In these sample descriptions, I need to parse these to pull the following items:

```
17OH = 17 Ohm
22OH = 22 Ohm
2P   = 2 Pole
2G   = 2-Gang
3G   = 3-Gang
TRK  = Track
2YR  = 2-Year Warranty
1YR  = 1-Year Warranty
```

The legacy application is written in VBScript/Classic ASP, and so the following would be an example of a way to convert these to English.

```
descriptionOUTPUT = ""
descriptionRAW = "17OH 2P 2G TRK 2YR"
if instr(descriptionRAW,"17OH") > 0 then descriptionOUTPUT = descriptionOUTPUT & "17 Ohm "
if instr(descriptionRAW,"22OH") > 0 then descriptionOUTPUT = descriptionOUTPUT & "22 Ohm "
if instr(descriptionRAW,"2P") > 0 then descriptionOUTPUT = descriptionOUTPUT & "2 Pole "
if instr(descriptionRAW,"2G") > 0 then descriptionOUTPUT = descriptionOUTPUT & "2 Gang "
if instr(descriptionRAW,"3G") > 0 then descriptionOUTPUT = descriptionOUTPUT & "3 Gang "
if instr(descriptionRAW,"TRK") > 0 then descriptionOUTPUT = descriptionOUTPUT & "Track "
if instr(descriptionRAW,"2YR") > 0 then descriptionOUTPUT = descriptionOUTPUT & "2-Year Warranty "
if instr(descriptionRAW,"1YR") > 0 then descriptionOUTPUT = descriptionOUTPUT & "1-Year Warranty "
response.write(descriptionOUTPUT)
```

The output would be:

```
17 Ohm 2 Pole 2 Gang Track 2-Year Warranty
```

This would be fine if we just had a dozen or so items to parse out, but we probably have hundreds of these and the repetition of the "`if instr`" statements are surely hugely inefficient even if we're only running that code a couple hundred times per day. Is there a better way to do this using an array or Regex, or anything more efficient than the above?

Comment: You should use a lookup table driven from a database, it would make this far easier to manage and reduce the code smell.

Comment: They will come from the database, I just didn't want to overcomplicate the question when the worry is more about the code utilized rather than the source of the items that needed to be looked up.

Comment: @Beems Consider using the `Replace`  function.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14973169

Comment: Look if they are coming from the database anyway, the code can be a one / two liner for every iteration was the point I was trying to make.

Answer (score 1):

A very basic way would be to use the dictionary object in asp.
Either hard code them or read them from database and compare in a loop.

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_dictionary.asp

Comment: I will look into this, thanks. Can you link any good examples that are applicable to this scenario?

Comment: Why add a dictionary if you already have a recordset?

Comment: As I said either hard code them (like the original) OR read from a db.

Answer (score -1):

Bit late to answer this, but in case you're still looking, this is fairly straightforward using the replace command:

```
descriptionOUTPUT = replace(replace(replace(descriptionRAW,"OH"," ohm"),"P"," Pole"),"G","-Gang")
response.write(descriptionOUTPUT)
```